# csrf token without jsp (spring mvc)

Tags: spring, rest, security, token, csrf

I enabled csrf token in config of Spring security. But how mobile device recieve csrf token? When I had jsp, it looked like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='${_csrf.parameterName}' value='${_csrf.token}'/>
```

But now I have no jsp... so any way to send csrf manually?

Comment: Have you declared it in spring security config xml?

Comment: When we access the service from a different domain it will be better to disable csrf tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular practice is to code a filter to attach the token as a cookie. Your client then sends a GET request first to fetch that cookie. For the subsequent requests, that cookie is then sent back as a header.

You can look at the official [Spring Angular guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_csrf_protection), and refer to [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon)'s source code for a detailed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a stateless CSRF protection. One solution [nicely explained by Robbert van Waveren](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/) is to *have the clients generate and send the same unique secret value in both a Cookie and a custom HTTP header*:

> Considering a website is only allowed to read/write a Cookie for its
>   own domain, only the real site can send the same value in both
>   headers. Using this approach all your server has to do is check if
>   both values are equal, on a stateless per request basis!

Answer (score 0):

You may obtain it by looking inside of the `_csrf` attribute.

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/csrf_token")
public class CsrfTokenController {
    @GetMapping
    public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");

        return token.getToken();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If CSRF is enabled, you have to include a _csrf.token in the page you want to login or logout. Otherwise, both login and logout function will be failed.

[Refer this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/) for more help.

**EDIT:** You can get csrf token from request and send it according to your need. I have shared two references for csrf token please go through them. It will help you.

> [First Ref](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/04/csrf-defense-in-spring-mvc-31.html)
>   [Second Ref](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2014/10/31/restful-authentication-using-spring-security-on-spring-boot-and-jquery-as-a-web-client/)